# how to show a twig collection in grav

Tags: twig, grav

My problem is:
If I have a page written this way:
(saved home.en.md)

```
title: 'Home'
published: true
metadata:
    keywords: 'home'
taxonomy:
category:        - main
tag: - 'home'
menu: 'Home'
   slug: home
process:
    twig: true
routable: true
cache_enable: true
visible: true
content:
    items: @root
    order:
        by: date
       dir: desc 
    limit: 10
    pagination: true
---
This are all our pages:
```

how and where do I have to add the twig text?

```
{% for p in page.collection %}
 <h3> {{ p.title }} </h3>
 {{ p.summary }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by adding

```
template: name-of-template
```

and in my themes folder I added a name-of-template.html.twig :

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
<ul>
{% for p in page.collection %}

    <h3> {{ p.title }} </h3>
    {{ p.summary }} <br>
   <a href="http://example.com{{p.url}}"> {{ p.title }} </a> <br>
   {# could return http://example.com/my-section/my-category/my-blog-post #}

{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

I hope this will  help someone!